# Array sorting, Array input, Array Output

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with this program. It is meant to input random numbers into an array, change its dimensions, sort them, the output the sorted array. For some reason, the array will only fill with one number (-858993460) and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void InputArray(int[][5], int, int);
void OutputArray(int[], int);
void SelectionSort(int[], int);
void CopyArray(int[][5], int, int, int[], int);


int main()
{
    int sample_1[80];
    int sample_2[16][5];

    InputArray(sample_2, 16, 5);

    CopyArray(sample_2, 16, 5, sample_1, 80);

    cout << "Before sorting, contents of the array:" << endl << "----------------------" << endl;
    OutputArray(sample_1, 80);

    SelectionSort(sample_1, 80);

    cout << "After sorting, contents of the array:" << endl << "----------------------" << endl;
    OutputArray(sample_1, 80);

    return 0;
}

//generate random numbers for a two dimensional array
void InputArray(int array[][5], int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = rand() % 1000;
        }
    }
}

//display values in a one-dimensional array
void OutputArray(int array[], int number)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << "\t";
    }
}

// selection sort of a one-dimensional array
void SelectionSort(int numbers[], int array_size)
{
    int i, j, a;
    for (i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < array_size; ++j) {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[j]) {
                a = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }


    return;
}

//x and y and two dimensions of array_2d; n is the dimension of array_1d
//copy values from array_2d[][] to array_1d[]
//assume x*y equals n
void CopyArray(int array_2d[][5], int x, int y, int array_1d[], int n)
{
    memcpy(array_2d, array_1d, sizeof(array_1d));


    return;
}
```

Comment: Only call `srand` once per program. I suggest you use `std::vector` and `std::copy` as your debugger can bounds check them and spot lots of common errors immediately. Also `sizeof(array_1d)` doesn't work on function parameters (or rather, it doesn't return the array size).

Answer (score 0):

```
void CopyArray(int array_2d[][5], int x, int y, int array_1d[], int n)
{
    memcpy(array_2d, array_1d, sizeof(array_1d));
}
```

That's your problem right there. The size of the array_1d is unspecified here. The sizeof() operator does not know the size of the array that's being copied.

In fact, I'm surprised that this even compiles, although I'm too lazy to test it with gcc.

What you need to do is calculate the size of the array yourself, multiply it by sizeof(int), and use that instead of the existing sizeof() operator.

Comment: `sizeof` on an array function parameter will give the size of the pointer.

Comment: Indeed, you beat me to it. I just ran a quick little test, and gcc yelled very loudly at me. Which compiler was used here isn't specified, but at least gcc will tell you, very loudly, that you're doing it wrong...

Comment: I am using Visual Studio as a compiler. I'm still having some difficulty understanding what needs to be fixed. The input functions were written already when I started this so I am hesitant to say they are the issue, of course, I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: I pointed you to CopyArray() is being the issue here. What led you to believe that I was referring to InputArray(), which I never mentioned? If CopyArray() was "written already", then whoever wrote CopyArray() was wrong.

Comment: The above comment pertaining to the use of srand, not your comment, sorry that was not clear